# Recover "Store only" 7z file

Tags: data-recovery, 7-zip, file-corruption

My laptop is running Manjaro (kernel 5.5). I went to make a 7z archive using the **p7zip** package. Specifically, my command was

```
$ 7za a -mmt -mx0 -t7z ARCHIVE.7z Directory/
```

The source directory was quite large so the archive ended up being ~21GB. Mostly video files from a presentation.

However, when I went to unzip it on another machine, it threw a Header Error (could not open as 7z archive or something along those lines). I attempted to follow the steps for that specific error [from the 7zip docs](https://7-zip.org/recover.html), but all that did was make the OS think the archive was 89MiB, which obviously it is not.

Since I created the archive with Store, I'm hoping there is a way to recover the data. In fact using ghex I was able to see bits and pieces of raw data from various text files in the archive. Any tips on how to go about this? I still have the original broken archive as well, not just the failed 89MiB one.

Comment: Was the archive transferred via FTP maybe?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, I archived it on one machine and put it on an NTFS formatted USB drive.